# I get a runtime error when I use the MonthName function within a For loop

Tags: excel, vba

With the below code I get a runtime error 9. It is a for loop that runs from 1 to 12. It activates worksheets that start with the month abbreviation.

If I comment out the for loop and replace k with a 1, it works. Within the for loops, I tried to msgbox the string, but everything looks fine as well.

I'm a bit stumped on what I am missing.

```
Option Explicit
Sub activatews()

Dim MonthWS As Worksheet, WB As Workbook, StringMonth As String, k As Integer

Set WB = ThisWorkbook

For k = 1 To 12
StringMonth = MonthName(k, True)
StringMonth = StringMonth & "-Belastung"
Set MonthWS = WB.Sheets(StringMonth)

MonthWS.Activate

Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `Set MonthWS = WB.Sheets(StringMonth)` throws the error because the workbook has no sheet with the respective name.

Comment: Debug your code with F8. Maybe when `k=1` it works, but you need to know which value holds `k` when it fails. F8 will execute code step by step for debugging.

Comment: I thought that too, so I tried with replacing the k with a 1 and it worked. I believe it is the for loop but I am not sure why.

Comment: I will try that!

Comment: Are your Worksheets named `Jan-Belastung`, `Feb-Belastung`... or `Januar-Belastung`,`Februar-Belastung`? `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook containing this code. If you want refer to another workbook, then do so.

Comment: Use `Debug.Print StringMonth` below the line `StringMonth = StringMonth & "-Belastung"` and outcomment the two remaining lines. Now see in the `Immediate window` if these are the names of the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue! It gave the error at the month march because it was using the German spelling while the worksheet used the English spelling. So Mrz-Belastung (incorrect) instead of Mar-Belastung.

I will rename the worksheets to reflect the German spelling. Thank you everyone for the tips!

Comment: Although you have solved your issue, I have written a post which helps VBA programmers who need to write international code.   https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2020/10/internationalise-dates-in-vba.html

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this without the `MonthName` function:

```
Option Explicit

Sub activateWS()
    
    Dim Mnths As Variant
    Mnths = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", _
                  "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
    
    Dim MonthWS As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim StringMonth As String
    Dim k As Long
    
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    
    For k = LBound(Mnths) To UBound(Mnths)
        StringMonth = Mnths(k)
        StringMonth = StringMonth & "-Belastung"
        Debug.Print StringMonth
        'Set MonthWS = WB.Sheets(StringMonth)
        'MonthWS.Activate
    Next k

End Sub
```